# Is there a way to propagate changes to variables within a class instance to other class instances derived from it?

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, composition

**Problem**: What I want to achieve is to have an instance of a `Parent` class propagate changes of its local variables to `Child` class instances derived directly from the `Parent`. My current approach is to `extend` the `Parent` class to the `Child`s but it doesn't provide any way to access the `Parent` instance variables.

**Example**: Let's say that the parent class stores a `String` which contains a name. I want 1 child to stem from a parent whose `String` name is "George" and 1 other child to stem from a parent whose `String` name is "Nick". When the `String` stored in the "George" parent class changes from "George" to "Patrick" I want it to be changed for his child but not for the child of "Nick".

Can this be done without too much computational overhead?

**Code Reference**:

```
public class Parent {
    private String name;

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void changeName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private String parentName;
    /**
     * Currently derives the String directly which won't react to
     * changes to the Parent class.
     */
    public Child(Parent p) {
        this.parentName = p.getName();
    }

    public getParentName() {
        return parentName;
    }
}

public class mainApp {
    public static void main(String[] cmdArgs) {
        Parent George = new Parent("George");
        Parent Nick = new Parent("Nick");

        Child a = new Child(George);
        Child b = new Child(Nick);

        George.changeName("Patrick");

        // Prints "George", should print "Patrick"
        System.out.println(a.getParentName());

        // Prints "Nick", should print "Nick"
        System.out.println(b.getParentName());
    }
}
```

**Solution**: It is actually possible to achieve the above by using [Object Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

By keeping a reference to the original `Parent` that was used when creating the `Child` class instance, all changes conducted on the `Parent` instance will be reflected on the `Child` instance.

In this way, a `Child` can also be in an *orphaned* state where no `Parent` instance was used to create it.

**Solution Code**:

```
public class Parent {
    private String name;

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void changeName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

// Extension is not required
public class Child {
    private Parent parentReference;

    public Child(Parent parentReference) {
        this.parentReference = parentReference;
    }

    public getParentName() {
        // We need to manually handle the case of a non-existent parent
        if (parentReference == null) {
            return "None";
        } else {
            return parentReference.getName();
        }
    }
}

public class mainApp {
    public static void main(String[] cmdArgs) {
        Parent George = new Parent("George");
        Parent Nick = new Parent("Nick");

        Child a = new Child(George);
        Child b = new Child(Nick);
        Child c = new Child(null);

        George.changeName("Patrick");

        // Prints "Patrick", should print "Patrick"
        System.out.println(a.getParentName());

        // Prints "Nick", should print "Nick"
        System.out.println(b.getParentName());

        // Prints "None", should print "None"
        System.out.println(c.getParentName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yours appears to me to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are tying to get a code solution that uses inheritance while the best solution is likely not to use inheritance at all, but rather composition. These "children" you speak of should be considered like node objects in a collection tree, not child classes.

Comment: He's only just learning loops, don't hit him with composition yet :p

Comment: @Neilos: perhaps, but you have to admit that he's barking up the wrong tree. This is not solved by inheritance.

Comment: I am currently already implementing a solution where I am not using inheritance at all but rather storing the "parent" object directly inside the subclasses. However, I just wanted to know if it is possible with inheritance. We were asked to do an exercise with inheritance but the problem itself is really rather not what inheritance would successfully solve efficiently.

Comment: OK, I can answer that for you: NO. This is not what inheritance is for. It's for inheriting *behavior*.

Comment: I can understand that, but I need to inherit behavior whilst keeping certain variables common. Hence why I wanted to utilize inheritance. Currently I am just copy pasting all the methods of the "parent" class into the "children" classes and just putting the line parentClass.methodToBeCalled(); inside.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with what nodes are although I have read a bit on what interfaces are.

Comment: Forget about inheritance to solve your problem. You need to understand and actually use composition

Comment: I think that the issue is that he is not describing his problem properly, I suspect that he is actually trying to do something that is trivially solved with inheritance but the way he is describing it is making it seem as though it isn't.

Comment: Edited original question with a bit of code showcasing what I want to achieve.

Comment: It is still quite unclear what you are trying to achieve, from your code it looks as though there is no need to subclass `Parent`.

Comment: [@FedericoPeraltaSchaffner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1876620/federico-peralta-schaffner) that is exactly what I am currently using ("I am currently already implementing a solution where I am not using inheritance at all but rather storing the "parent" object directly inside the subclasses.") after reading a bit on it on the web. The university forces us to use inheritance so I have created 2 versions of the same exercise.

Comment: What is the problem they game you? It may just be that you are interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: @Neilos to be completely honest with you, the problem itself is with the exercise's actual wordings. They actually do not make any sense and what sense I actually made of it along with 3 other people they are asking us to essentially waste memory which I find kind of absurd. A small snippet translated is added on the question.

Comment: Ok, now we see that this is a much more complex problem than you were first describing, not that it should be difficult to do but I can see that it could both be achieved through composition and inheritance. In the real world I would definitely use composition for this for the simple fact that as the services expand you will get cases where you want to merge functionality from services that have actually diverged, for instance a car and a horse are both vehicles but cars have wheels and horses don't, this is all good until you want to add functionality for passengers!

Comment: @AlexPapageorgiou I gave you an inheritance only example check out my updated answer. Like others say, composition is really the best approach but I've tried to address your actual question instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141965/discussion-between-alex-papageorgiou-and-neilos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the terms "Parent" and "Child" in a very literal sense in your example but that is not always applicable.

You can only use inheritance when there is a fixed relationship between a type and a subtype. Like, "a Bicycle is a Vehicle" or a "Giraffe is an Animal". Those relations are the same for every instance of Bicycle and Giraffe. But what you're describing is not like this.

For your case, you can use composition to model.

- Every `Person` has a `name`.
- Every `Person` has a `parent` (which may be left `null` to indicate "don't know" or "don't care")
- Every `Person` has zero or more `children`

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Person parent;

    Person(String name, Person parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    // etc (getters, setters)
}

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] cmdArgs) {
        Person george = new Person("George", null);
        Person nick = new Person("Nick", null);
        Person a = new Person("a", george);
        Person b = new Person("b", george);
        Person c = new Person("c", nick);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using inheritance for your actual stated problem, it's pretty convoluted and you will run into problems as you begin to expand your services (composition would be a better real world approach but composition comes with a greater learning curve to start with but gives the added benefits of greater flexibility):

```
public abstract class ServiceProvider {

  private String providerName;
  private String clientName;

  public ServiceProvider(String providerName, String clientName) {
    this.providerName = providerName;
    this.clientName = clientName;
  }

  public String getProviderName() {
    return this.providerName;
  }

  public String getClientName() {
    return this.clientName;
  }

  boolean validateContract();

}

public class MobileInternetProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  public MobileInternetProvider(String providerName, String clientName) {
    super(providerName, clientName);
  }

  public boolean validateContract() {
    return ContractService.validateMobileInternetProvider(this.getClientName());
  }

}

public abstract class MobileCellularProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  public MobileCellularProvider(String providerName, String clientName) {
    super(providerName, clientName);
  }

  public boolean validateContract() {
    return ContractService.validateMobileCellularProvider(getContractNumber());
  }

  String getContractNumber();

}

public class MobileCellularProviderCardContract extends MobileCellularProvider {

  public MobileCellularProviderCardContract(String providerName, String clientName) {
    super(providerName, clientName);
  }

  public String getContractNumber() {
    MobileContractService.getCardContractNumber(this.getClientName());
  }

}

public class MobileCellularProviderMobileContract extends MobileCellularProvider {

  public MobileCellularProviderMobileContract(String providerName, String clientName) {
    super(providerName, clientName);
  }

  public String getContractNumber() {
    MobileContractService.getMobileContractNumber(this.getClientName());
  }

}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
ArrayList<ServiceProvider> serviceProviders = new ArrayList<>();
serviceProviders.add(new MobileCellularProviderMobileContract(ProviderDef.PROVIDER_1, "Client 1"));
serviceProviders.add(new MobileCellularProviderMobileContract(ProviderDef.PROVIDER_1, "Client 2"));
serviceProviders.add(new MobileCellularProviderCardContract(ProviderDef.PROVIDER_1, "Client 3"));
serviceProviders.add(new MobileInternetProvider(ProviderDef.PROVIDER_1, "Client 4"));
serviceProviders.add(new MobileInternetProvider(ProviderDef.PROVIDER_2, "Client 1"));
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

When a subclass is instantiated it has the superclass' fields, therefore there is no distinction between updating the subclass' `name` field and updating a superclass' `name` field... there is only one field in the instance.

So when you say:

> For example, let's say that the parent class stores a String which contains a name. I want 3 children to stem from a parent whose String name is "George" and 3 other children to stem from a parent whose String name is "Nick". When the String stored in the "George" parent class changes from "George" to "Patrick" I want it to be changed for its children but not for the children of "Nick".

this doesn't really make sense.

The title of your question says

> Is there any way for a parent class' instance's variables to be directly referenced by its children (subclasses)?

The answer is Yes! But your problem that you describe is not related to the title of the question

Comment: I think the downvotes are referring to the wording. "updating a subclass' fields and updating a superclass' fields...they are the same thing" makes it look like they are actually the same memory reference which they are not, at least as far as I know.

Comment: My answer is a little ambiguous, what I was trying to say was that an instantiated class is both an instance of itself and its superclass, therefore if a superclass has a field `name` then the subclass will *inherit* this field, it may not have access to it but there will only be one reference for the instance, not a seperate reference for the subclass and the superclass, which is what I think you were implying in your question, that just makes no sense.

Comment: If that's the case I think I do not exactly understand what a reference is. What I mean by "reference" I mean as a "memory reference", as in the actual content contained within the variable. For example, the variable y in the following code refers to the "memory reference" of the variable x.

    Object x = new Object();
    Object y = x;

Comment: But we are talking instances not classes. So in an instance the subclass inherits the superclass' fields meaning the `name` field will only be stored once in memory for the *instance* not for the subclass and superclass individually.

Comment: Basically (I may be wrong), but from your question I got the impression that you misunderstood inheritance and the relationship between a superclass and a subclass.

Comment: You are still inputting the name of the Provider in the constructor, meaning you are creating a new variable in-memory which stores the "Provider 1" String which is what I want to avoid and what this question is about.

Comment: @AlexPapageorgiou Yes, the provider string is stored once per instance but you can get round that by passing static references if you wish, it's not that big a deal, the logic I wrote however addresses using inheritance. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AlexPapageorgiou I have answered both the question in your title and the question from the exercise book, if this doesn't help you then I'm not sure what it is that you are looking for :)